# JApplet Session Tracking

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, japplet

I going to build J2EE application using jsp, Servlet and Java Beans +MySQL.

I am using Applet as front-end for the user.

Before going to ask question let consider that many user use Applet(Presentation layer) for to communicate with the Server.

My Question is that how can we maintain the session tracking mechanism in Applet that server should to be know whom user perform which activity like in JSP there are implicit object "session". But how can we perform similar with applet

Comment: yes sure . because Applet give us swings or many built-in graphical component . that's make my work easy. so this is the reason

Comment: like swing component give me progress bar , button , radio , slider ,table etc etc...

Comment: yes  i have heard Google web tool kit. but now there is now more time to learn this technologies from scratch.